# Understanding the definition of XML parser

Tags: xml, xsd

On [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/), there are some [advantages/strengths listed about XML Schemas](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp).

What is meant by the following point:

> You can use your XML parser to parse your Schema files

Comment: The author is trying to point to the fact that since a schema file is basically an xml so you don't need anything special to parse the schema files. You every day XML parsers such as saxon.

Comment: Except that since the question asks what an "XML parser" is, we ought to be a bit more precise. Saxon is not an XML parser.

Answer (score 2):

Generically, in computer science, a parser is a piece of software that takes a string of characters as input, and determines its structure by reference to a grammar. For an XML parser, that grammar is the set of rules concerning start tags, end tags, attributes and the like, so the job of an XML parser is to take a raw XML document as input and turn it into something structured where the elements and attributes have been identified.

Unfortunately you will find as many people misusing the term as using it correctly. There are a lot of questions on StackOverflow (I've seen a couple today) where people talk about "writing an XML parser", when what they are actually doing is writing an XML application that processes the output of an XML parser.

The W3C XML specification doesn't actually use the term "XML parser"; it talks about an "XML processor". I think the reason for that is that an XML processor is doing more than just parsing. It also does some consistency checking (checking that start and end tags match) which in the pure computer science sense is not the job of a parser, and it may also do validation (checking that the elements identified by the parser conform to the rules in some DTD or schema).

One of the advantages of using XML to represent any kind of data is that you don't have to write your own parser; there are plenty of XML parsers that you can use for the job. The W3Schools site that you quote is simply pointing out that this applies to schemas as much as to any other kind of structured data.

Responding to the comment by @Zafar, Saxon is not an XML parser (though it's not uncommon to find people calling it that). Saxon includes a number of tools for processing XML, using languages such as XPath, XSLT, and XQuery, but Saxon doesn't parse the XML itself; it calls on the services of an external XML parser to do that. However, the ability to use generic XML tools like Saxon is another of the benefits of representing your data in XML, and is probably of even more value than the ability to reuse the XML parser itself.

Comment: "applies to schemas" means xsd? What is meant by "any other kind of structured data."

Answer (score 1):

XML Schema uses XML syntax and therefore can be parsed using a standard XML parser.  This is an advantage over DTD, for example, which cannot be parsed as XML, and allows for some very practical benefits:

- XSLT can parse an XML Schema to generate documentation or
  transform one XML Schema to another related XML Schema.
- Schematron can parse an XML Schema to check for conformance to
  sector or other organization guidelines/policy.
- JAXB and `xsd.exe` can parse an XML Schema to 
  generate classes in Java or .NET that support marshalling and
  unmarshalling automatically.

These benefits were easier to deliver because XML Schema uses XML syntax to express its constraints.